# Jquery mobile listview + phonegap bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

iv got a listview inside my jquery mobile + phonegap app, like:" `<li>test<ul><li>insidetest</li>
<li>insidetest2</li> ...`  " . the problem is that if in the name of "test" has an space character " " or a special character "ç, í , á , _" it goes though an infinite load animation and didn't render to the list's nodes page. i would like to know what to do to fix it.

Comment: What code is causing the trouble?

Comment: the firft <li>, if inside it have an space or a special character the code bugs.this bugs "<li>x_x<ul>",or "<li>code example<ul>" and this doesnt "<li>codeok<ul>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide us the jqm and phonegap version and the html used please?

I do a lot of listviews with data un jp, with latin american chars and russian and never have problem, maybe you need to refresh the listview with the method:

$('#mylistview_ID').listview("refresh");